# Setting up Git repo with other Git repo with Submodule? (WordPress development)

Tags: wordpress, git

I have a Git project/repo called "ABC" to which I would like to add WordPress among other things.

```
ABC
  WordPress
  Other 
  Stuff
```

Ideally I would like to base my WordPress setup on the [WordPress Skeleton](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton) repo.
(The WordPress Skeleton also contains a submodule referring to the latest stable WordPress release.)

How do I go about creating this setup?

1. Should I fork the WordPress-skeleton vs copy it into my existing repo?
2. How do I update the submodule that the WP-skeleton refers to from my ABC git repo?

I guess I am confused regarding the use of forks in this scenario when I want the ABC to contain code from other repos that in themselves have submodules.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are looking for is a tool to manage multiple repos. Here are few:

```
repo (http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html)
gitslave (http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/)
```

Also beware of submodule gotchas':

http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/

Answer (score 0):

@dani I did something like that. I created this git project: http://stechico.github.io/wordpress-skeleton/

Code samples there if any. HTH